# jquery or CSS dim the rest of the images when mouse is hovered over one

Tags: jquery, css, image, bootstrap-4

Do I have to use jquery or CSS or a combination of both to have the rest of the images that are inside bootstrap cards dim while the mouse is hovering over an image and change the opacity property of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Use the css property in Jquery. Try using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: what's the selector do I use in the jquery to change the other images' CSS value that is not being hovered over?  Do I do it in a loop or another way?

Comment: if you have the buttons in a class you can set them individually. For loop works too,for instance, If class[i] !== event.target...